# How to backup redis data in pvc of kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, database-backups, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

As mentioned in the title, I have an eks kubernetes cluster in aws, I have a redis service, and persist redis data through pvc, Storageclass Provisioner is aws-ebs, is there any way to backup my redis data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the AOF here as a persistent storage, and at the same time I used kubernetes pvc to store this AOF file, the provider is aws EBS, what I want to ask is whether there is a backup of kubernetes pvc volume Recovery plan